# Using Eigen Matrix as template

Tags: templates, eigen, eigen3

Kindly help me convert this function so that it can accept MatrixXf, Matrix3f, Matrix4f, I read the Eigen manual which recommends using MatrixBase but that didn't work, neither did the Eigen::Ref class. Thank you.

```
void MatrixIO::FEigentoFile(const Eigen::MatrixXf& in_mat,
                            const std::string filename)
{
  fmat fmat_pb;
  fmat_pb.set_rows(in_mat.rows());
  fmat_pb.set_cols(in_mat.cols());
  fmat_pb.mutable_data()->Reserve(in_mat.rows() * in_mat.cols());
  for (int i = 0; i < in_mat.rows(); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < in_mat.cols(); j++)
    {
      float c = in_mat(i, j);
      fmat_pb.add_data(c);
    }
  }
  std::fstream output(filename,
                      std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc | std::ios::binary);
  if (!fmat_pb.SerializeToOstream(&output))
  {
    LOG(INFO) << "Failed to write to file." << std::endl;
  }
  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename Derived>
void FEigentoFile(const Eigen::EigenBase<Derived> &in_mat, const std::string filename)
```

This should accept MatrixX* as argument.